# How to group rows by column name and sort rows by datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I need to order rows by date and time grouping them by `ID`:

```
df =

ID   TYPE  DATETIME
1    A     12/18/2015 23:02:00
1    A     12/17/2015 12:00:09
1    A     12/18/2015 18:04:08
2    B     12/20/2015 15:03:05
2    B     12/18/2015 14:02:07
```

The result should be this one:

result =

```
ID   TYPE  DATETIME
1    A     12/17/2015 12:00:09
1    A     12/18/2015 18:04:08
1    A     12/18/2015 23:02:00
2    B     12/18/2015 14:02:07
2    B     12/20/2015 15:03:05
```

How can I do it?

```
df.groupby("ID").sort(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
df.sort_values(['ID', 'DATETIME'], ascending=[True, True])
```

(I think df.sort() is now deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and specify columns by parameter `by`, `ascending` can be omit if need default ascending sorting:

```
#if df['DATETIME'].dtype != datetime, convert first
df.DATETIME = pd.to_datetime(df.DATETIME)

df = df.sort_values(by=['ID','TYPE','DATETIME'])
print (df)

   ID TYPE            DATETIME
1   1    A 2015-12-17 12:00:09
2   1    A 2015-12-18 18:04:08
0   1    A 2015-12-18 23:02:00
4   2    B 2015-12-18 14:02:07
3   2    B 2015-12-20 15:03:05
```